# default value of a created SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

hello I am trying to use the sqlite database on android to push an integer array and store it in the database then use it and update it on demand. what i do not understand is that android has a create or open function for the sqlite database
what is the default value of created database containing an integer column? is it 0? and if i am running the program for the first time i should use the create then each consecutive run should use open how can i separate them ?
i have created the databases using

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openOrCreateDatabase("MyDB", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable(isChkd INT(1));");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, there will not be any values in a table that you have just created and not entered any data in. It will resolve to null and if you did try to access data without having made any entries, you will get a NullPointerException. You could set the default value to be entered in a column by setting the DEFAULT flag.

Once you have created a database in onCreate(), you only need to call getReadableDatabase() or getWritableDatabase() on an instance of an object of the class which extends SQLLiteOpenHelper to execute your queries.

Comment: thank you... can i test if a table exists in the databases created ? without created the table only (if table(exists)) ?
will using getcolumnindex helps ?

Comment: You could try to get the columnIndex and surround this with a try/catch statement for catching a NullPointerException. If the table does not exist, it will throw a null pointer exception which you can catch to determine what you might want to do after that.

Answer (score 1):

Android uses SQLite. If you want to be sure just specify a default value, [as seen in the documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), [resp. here](http://sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#column-constraint):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MyTable (isChkd INT(1) DEFAULT 0)
```

Comment: thank you, is there an sql command to create the database with specific size ? as (isChkd INT(1) DEFAULT 0 SIZE)?

Comment: what do you consider "specific size"? are you talking about the column storage size?

Comment: yes i am checking out sql commands to get the column size and if i can initialize a column with a specific size instead of using loop commands